# adding a special section to a linux kernel module

Tags: linux, module, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

when using the normal `attribute section` syntax in a kernel module this section is not auto generated.

i am trying to put data on a special section from different places in the source code at compile-time, and then use the section `start` and `end` symbols to retrieve all the data in that section during runtime.

placing symbol in section `foo`:

```
...
int var_on_foo __attribute__((section("foo"))) = 10;
...
```

and then trying to access section `foo`:

```
int* first_foo = __start_foo;
....
```

using this in userspace works totally fine as the compiler just compiles in all the sections into the elf. but using this in a kernel module results in an error:

```
[  192.586590] simple_test: Unknown symbol __start_foo (err -2)
```

How can i tell kbuild to compile in all my special sections?

Comment: Check whether your compiled module (`.ko` file) actually contains the sections and the symbols you use. If there is no such section in the module, then it is probably a linker script which is responsible for that. If the module contains section and symbols, then you probably need to modify module loading procedure for load new section: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.2.9/source/kernel/module/main.c#L2694

Comment: Ok after reading up Kernel Code and kbuild linker scripts, it seems that kbuild will only include a strict list of predefined sections into the final .ko :-(

Comment: You may patch the linker script to include more.

Comment: Yes I found out how to add sections. But now to get the Section begin and end pointers or seems that I need to do the whole elf parsing by hand in my module init as there seems to be no way how to access the module_info struct from inside the module itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so here half an answer that might be enough for most people:

the sections are compiled in and the section will in most cases not be striped out (as striping kernel modules is considered a bad thing).

BUT accessing the data as in userland with the section start end symbols is not possible as the kernel ko elf loader (modules.c - load_module ...) will not take care to set this symbols.

**1. Solution:** (hardcore)

The **hardcore** solution would be to modify the load_module function to get access to the mod_info struct where the offsets to the sections and symbols are parsed.

**2. Solution:**

If your goal of using sections is to be able to collect data from various places of your module within one place, the easier way might be this:

```c
#include <linux/elf.h>
#include <linux/kallsyms.h>
#include <linux/module.h>

__attribute__((used)) static void barA(void)
{
    static char my_value[] = "i want to be free";
    static char *_magic_meta_string_my_value __attribute__((used)) = my_value;
}

__attribute__((used)) static void barB(void)
{
    static char my_value[] = "i want to break free";
    static char *_magic_meta_string_my_value_foo_bar_baz __attribute__((used)) = my_value;
}

static int __init init_magic_meta_section(void)
{
    const struct mod_kallsyms *const kallsyms = THIS_MODULE->kallsyms;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < kallsyms->num_symtab; i++) {

        const Elf_Sym *const ksym = &kallsyms->symtab[i];
        const char *const name = &kallsyms->strtab[ksym->st_name];
        static const char ref_name[] = "_magic_meta_string";
        static const unsigned int ref_name_length = sizeof((ref_name)) - 1;

        if (strncmp(name, ref_name, ref_name_length) == 0) {
            const char *const section_name = name + ref_name_length + 1;
            const char *const first_dot = strchr(section_name, '.');
            const long section_name_length = (long)first_dot - (long)section_name;

            printk(KERN_INFO "symbol %u: %lx %lu %s for section %.*s\n", i, (uintptr_t)ksym->st_value,
                   (uintptr_t)ksym->st_size, name, section_name_length, section_name);

            const char **magic_ptr = (char **)ksym->st_value;

            printk(KERN_INFO "and here the magic: (%s)\n", *magic_ptr);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

in this case `_magic_meta_string` is a string we add to all symbols that we want to find again. and then we iterate about all module symbols and search for all symbols that start with this string.

not exactly the same thing as the sections_start and end symbols in userland but i guess in most cases enough.

Special thanks to [@jo5ta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18041890/jo5ta) for finding this out for me :)